# Mask cables in footage and change its color

Tags: video, tracking

I have a charge cable in the footage which I want to track the cable and change its color, here is how the footage looks like from the very first frame to the last frame:

The red point is where I want to put my tracking markers on

[image]

[image]

What I want to do is to re-construct the cable by using the dot on the cable, by re-construct the cable, I mean I want to connect the traking markers by curve/path then use the Geometry panel to set its Bevel depth in order to overlap the cable in the footage, now I have some problem,

I know how to do point tracking, I use makers on the real cable and I can track the markers, but how to connect the tracking point in Blender on first frame, then connect them by curves to re-construct cable, then go to the second frame and so on.
2.Is it reasonable to do the cable re-construct by this way, or is their other easy workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd put small black dots along the cable, track the dots, then use the point field to get the locations of where the curve points should be. Snap the cursor to the different tracking marker empties and then move the things to the cursor.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit about what is point field

Comment: Sorry was short on time when writing, basically when you start a new file in blender with VFX mode and import then track your footage. After solving it you will see a bunch of points. Select one in the 3d viewport and then right click and select snap. Snap cursor to selected. Then in the curves edit mode just use the 3d cursor as a guide for different points the curve needs to move along. From there you should be able to render a mask or to selectively recolour by rendering in black and white or with alpha or something.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a try getting home!